# Django шаблоны. Как перебрать словарь, который получается из функции с тремя параметрами

Tags: python, django, циклы, шаблонизаторы

У меня есть функция, которая возвращает словарь

```
{% build_ru_price_dict car_item.car_price car_item.release_date car_item.engine_volume %}
```

Как мне перебрать этот словарь в шаблоне?

Я пробовал:

```
{% for k, v build_ru_price_dict car_item.car_price car_item.release_date car_item.engine_volume.items %}
    {{ k }} -- {{ v }}
{% endfor %}
```

выдает ошибку:

```
'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for k, v build_ru_price_dict car_item.car_price car_item.release_date car_item.engine_volume.items
```

Comment: Я ошибся, забыл in. Но сути не меняет

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался

```
  {% build_ru_price_dict car_item.car_price car_item.release_date car_item.engine_volume as p_data %}
{% for k, v in p_data.items %}
  {{ k }} - {{ v }}
{% endfor %}
```